# we need to filter a table by date any one knows what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**It's a work**

We want to sort/filter the tabel that is the result of this code by orderdatum translation = "orderdate or data of pursches" anyone thats know what to do  we are at an dead end we have tride to google but everything we get are the wrong type of code that we need to make this work. we know that we should not use root and  stuff like that but this is for a school projekt.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "garp";

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
/*    $query = $_GET['query']; */
    $orderkund = $_GET['Orderkundinput']; 
    $artikel = $_GET['Artikelinput']; 

    $min_length = 2;
    $artikelQuery="";
    $orderkundQuery="";
    if(strlen($artikel) >= $min_length){ 
        $artikel = htmlspecialchars($artikel); 

        $artikel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $artikel);
        $artikelQuery = " AND Artikelnr = '$artikel'";
    }
    if (strlen($orderkund) >= $min_length){ 
        $orderkund = htmlspecialchars($orderkund); 

        $orderkund = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $orderkund);
        $orderkundQuery = " AND OrderKund = '$orderkund'";
    }

    $query = $artikelQuery.$orderkundQuery;
    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $sql = "SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,Orderkund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K'".$query;
    $raw_results = $conn->query ($sql);

        $row_cnt = false === $raw_results ? 0 : $raw_results->num_rows;
        echo " <p class='rows'> Numbers of rows loaded: $row_cnt </p>";
        if($row_cnt > 0){
            while($raw_result = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                echo "<table class='table'><thead class='thead-light'><tr><th class='col'>".'Ordernummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'OrderserieIK'."</th><th class='col'>".'Orderkund'."</th><th class='col'>".'fakturakund'."</th><th class='col'>".'orderdatum'."</th><th class='col'>".'erreferens'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveratvarde'."</th><th class='col'>".'radnummer'."</th><th class='col'>".'artikelnr'."</th><th class='col'>".'benamning'."</th><th class='col'>".'leveranstid'."</th><th class='col'>".'Ursprungligtantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'Levereratantal'."</th><th class='col'>".'forspris'."</th><th class='col'>".'bruttopris'."</th><th class='col'>".'varukostnad'."</th></tr></thead>";
                echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$raw_result['Ordernummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['OrderserieIK']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Orderkund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Fakturakund']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Orderdatum']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Erreferens']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratvarde']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Radnummer']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Artikelnr']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Benamning']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Leveranstid']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Ursprungligtantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Levereratantal']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Forspris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Bruttopris']."</td><td>".$raw_result['Varukostnad']."</td></tr></tbody></table>";

            }
        }

        else{         
            echo "No return";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }

?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about `ORDER BY orderdatum` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? `order by` in your query lets you sort by a field

Comment: we need to order by specific numbers

Comment: If this a school assignment, it's probably in your books or has been covered in some lesson somehow. So pay attention in class, do your homework...!
Not looking at your code, but just giving a little tip, I always tend to store dates in yyyymmdd (number or varchar) format. That makes ordering dates very easy...

Comment: Share your current output and what type of output you expect.

Comment: first of we don't have any bocks for this class and this for a compeny we work here as school  students, and the farthest we come on the lessons i to  do a simpel login page

Comment: @dexter our current out put is a big tabel on somewhere betwen 1k to 24k rows and we need to sort it by date if you can do it php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: 01

add the following block of code:

```
AND WHERE (orderdatum BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate')
```

Comment: thats not relly what we want we all ready have it sorted from smallest to bigest we need to filter it betwen to  dates

Comment: I have made an edit. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: no we tride to  make it into a bit of code like the $orderkund and $orderkundQuery bit but we did not get it to work

Comment: how does your final query looks like ?

Comment: like this:                                                                                                        
Notice: Undefined variable: startDateQuery1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\dat\artikelnr.php on line 46
Numbers of rows loaded: 0

No return

Comment: what is the value of `$startDate` and `$endDate`  ?

Comment: before the line `$raw_results = $conn->query ($sql);`

Comment: the value of start data is set as 90929 and value of and date is 90930 we chose those because it was the first date in the table

Comment: this what we get now: SELECT OrderHuvud.Ordernummer ,OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK ,Orderkund ,Fakturakund ,Orderdatum ,Erreferens ,Levereratvarde ,Radnummer ,Artikelnr ,Benamning ,Leveranstid ,Ursprungligtantal ,Levereratantal ,Forspris ,Bruttopris ,Varukostnad FROM garp.OrderHuvud left join garp.OrderRad on OrderHuvud.Ordernummer = OrderRad.Ordernummer where OrderHuvud.OrderserieIK = 'K' AND WHERE (orderdatum BETWEEN '90828 ' AND '90930')' AND OrderKund = '15'